# How to change local file path url to local host url in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a local file path url like

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/
```

What I want is to convert the above link to

```
https://localhost ...
```

If it is possible please help me with this.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the `file:///` away from your original URL by accessing the `path` of it:

```
let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/jn/test/url")!
print(url.path) //prints /Users/jn/test/ur
```

Better yet, you can get the `pathComponents` of it:

```
let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/jn/test/url")!
print(url.pathComponents) //prints ["/", "Users", "jn", "test", "url"]
```

It's extremely unlikely that you'd be serving from `localhost` at the root directory (below `Users` even), so you'd have to decide how many path components you'd want and take just that section of the array. For example:

```
let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/jn/test/url")!
print(url.pathComponents) //["/", "Users", "jn", "test", "url"]
var convertedUrl = URL(string: "https://localhost" + url.pathComponents[1...].joined(separator: "/"))
print(convertedUrl) //Optional(https://localhostUsers/jn/test/url)
```

Note that I'm not doing any error handling here to make sure that the URLs or valid or that there are a certain number of path components available in the array, etc -- that'd all be up to you.

Comment: Just to get hold of what you said by changing the file and inserting https will we be getting the file?

Comment: I'm not sure what that question means. If you mean will you be able to access the same file using file:// and https://localhost, no, not unless you have a web server up and running to serve the file